# How to create a task application in Spring Data Flow Server and mount a remote directory using Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow, persistent-volumes

I have a local running cluster deployed with minikube. Spring Cloud Data Flow is deployed according to [this tutorial](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/kubectl/). At this time, I'm able to create a kubernetes task on the SCDF dashboard and launch it. Although I have a task which reads file from file system and I would like to read that file from a shared NFS directory mounted in the POD.

I have a NFS server configured and running in another virtual machine and there is a persistent volume created in my kubernetes cluster pointing to the NFS host. When launching a task, some parameters are provided.

```
  deployer.job-import-access-file.kubernetes.volumes=[
  {
    name: accessFilesDir,
    persistentVolumeClaim: {
      claimName: 'apache-volume-claim'
    }
  },
  {
    name: processedFilesDir,
    persistentVolumeClaim: {
      claimName: 'apache-volume-claim'
    }
  }
]deployer.job-import-access-file.kubernetes.volumeMounts=[
  {
    name: 'accessFilesDir',
    mountPath: '/data/apache/access'
  },
  {
    name: 'processedFilesDir',
    mountPath: '/data/apache/processed'
  }
]
```

nfs-volume.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-apache-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  nfs:
    server: 10.255.254.10
    path: '/var/nfs/apache'
```

nfs-volume-claim.yaml

```
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apache-volume-claim
  namespace: default
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Application Docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

COPY target/job-import-access-file-0.1.0.jar /opt/job-import-access-file-0.1.0.jar
VOLUME ["/data/apache/access", "/data/apache/processed"]

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/opt/job-import-access-file-0.1.0.jar"]
```

It is expected that my task reads files from the mounted directory. But directory is empty. I mean, it is mounted although there is no sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the actual issue in your case is the `name` of the volume you specified in the configuration properties. Since K8s doesn't allow upper case letters for the name (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#names)), you need to use lowercase for your `name` values (Currently there are accessFilesDir and processedFilesDir), etc.,

I tried to pass the similar settings on minikube (without NFS mounting etc.,) just to see if the task launching passes the volume and volume mount K8s deployer properties and they seem to work fine:

```
dataflow:>task create a1 --definition "timestamp"

dataflow:>task launch a1 --properties "deployer.timestamp.kubernetes.volumes=[{name: accessfilesdir, persistentVolumeClaim: { claimName: 'apache-volume-claim' }},{name: processedfilesdir, persistentVolumeClaim: { claimName: 'apache-volume-claim' }}],deployer.timestamp.kubernetes.volumeMounts=[{name: 'accessfilesdir', mountPath: '/data/apache/access'},{name: 'processedfilesdir', mountPath: '/data/apache/processed'}]"
```

and, this resulted in the following config when I describe the pod (kubectl describe ) of the launched task:

```
Volumes:
  accessfilesdir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  apache-volume-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  processedfilesdir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  apache-volume-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I was in a trap. I have made the changes sugested by you in the volume names and passed those configurations as properties and not as arguments. A lot of work because of a silly mistake.